# Custom Guest middleware not working as expected in Nuxt Project

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I am using `Nuxt auth module`. For login page i have created a custom middleware called `guest.js` which looks like this :

```
export default function ({ $auth, store, redirect }) {
    if (!process.server) {
     if ($auth.$state.loggedIn) {
             return redirect('/')
           }
      }
  }
```

and in `Login` component i have this : `middleware: 'guest'` .

Now the problem is when page is refreshed this does not work. Because at server side the user is false for `auth module`,

```
{ user: null, loggedIn: false, strategy: 'local' }
```

so i put small check on that but i think on refresh this middleware runs on server side only?. I am using `Universal` mode.

What should i do to get this to work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement here `if (!process.server)` is useless because middlewares are always on serverside if you use it on `universal`. They have changed it.

Comment: Thank you for answer. But then what is the workaround ?

Comment: i have done it like this: the user log in first and retrieve an token from the server, that token is stored then in a cookie. In my middleware i have a function that reads the cookie value of my token and then i check if that token is valid. If it is then he can move to the next side otherwise i send him back to the start page. Remember: You cant access the `window` object to access the cookies but you have access to the request header. so you can read the cookies from the request header

Comment: Well, Thank you for explanation. I will try this one :)